# Merge all .gpx files within a folder into one file with GPSbabel

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to use GPSbabel to merge all single `.gpx` files within one folder into one file called for example `merge.gpx` how can i archive something like this?

I know how to do it manually:

```
gpsbabel -i gpx -f "folder/of/file/1.gpx" -f "folder/of/file/2.gpx" -f "folder/of/file/3.gpx" -o gpx -F "folder/of/file/merge.gpx"
```

But because there are up to 20 such files within one folder i would like to use a batch (.bat) file to do this automatically?
I'm nearly completely new to batch files and could not find any information how to archive that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
cd "folder/of/file"
set f=
for %%f in (*.gpx) do set f=!f! -f "%%f"
gpsbabel -i gpx !f! -o gpx -F "merge.gpx"
```

Comment: Nice. I was just going to try another option (GPSBabel can read directions from batch (or command) files via the -b option) but this is more elegant.

Comment: Thats exactly what i needed. Thank you!

Comment: I also considered the -b option of GPSBabel but with all files being .gpx files I found that quite a hassle to fist build a list of the files and then run the command. Anyway GPSBabel is just a great tool but well the documentation for it in my opinion is not...

Comment: How would that be for linux?

Answer (score 10):

For Linux, you could use the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /folder/of/file
ff=""
for f in *.gpx
do 
    ff="$ff -f $f"
done
gpsbabel -i gpx $ff -o gpx -F "All.gpx"
```